# VS Code Restart The PC On Its Own after some time

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a long time I have been using VS Code but from 2-3 week I cannot use it as while working my pc randomly restart. For some time I think it was my pc's fault, then I recognize it happening only when I am working on VS Code. I cannot last 3–4 minutes doing work. I have tried reinstalling, deleting extension I don't know about, even deleting all data, I Have also tried deleting VS Code cached files multiple times, starting a new sync and try using older versions of VS Code. But the problem did not go. I have also tried using default setup of VS Code with no extensions installed and no change in settings. It automatically restarts on its own. Please help me with this issue.

VS Code version: Code 1.58.2 (c3f1263, 2021-07-14T22:10:15.214Z)
OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
Restricted Mode: No

Spec-
|CPUs|Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz (8 x 3600)|
|Memory (System)|15.94GB

Comment: Recently i have also tried using vs code insider and it's same situation with it too. I used it for 3-4 minutes and suddenly my pc restart same as vscode

Comment: sometimes VSC uses a lot of memory, if windows can't supply new memory it reboots

Comment: But most of the time my memory usage did not pass 8gb. So something or some setting is itself not suplying vscode memory?

Comment: I tried making vscode processes high priority but it didn't help. One thing i notice tho i used vscode for around 1hour and it worked perfectly fine but unfortunately after sometime it still restart.

Comment: It's not necessarily just a memory problem. Various other issues can cause an OS to restart, like an overworked CPU or overheating. If those don't solve your issue, you may need a new device. VSCode uses Electron, which is pretty CPU intensive. As I've heard, Sublime is pretty lightweight and may work for you.